# Where to place joins in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, java, sql, architecture, 3-tier

I'm trying to implement three tier architecture. Where i need to put the join statements of my database query?

i.e, If i have a Bill class it will have two tables BillingMaster and BillingDetail. For insert/update/delete i can use as follows

### DB Layer

```
Class BillingMaster
{
public int BillId;
public double BillAmt;
public void save()
{
      .....
  }
  public void update()
  {
      .....
  }
}
Class BillingDetatil
{
  public int BillId;
  public string Item;
  public double Amount;
  public void save()
  {
      .....
  }
  public void update()
  {
      .....
  }
}
```

I need to get the data and make them in a tabular format joining billingmst and billingdet. Where i need to give the join query?

----------I'm Modifiying question with respect to the inputs i got from Kayaman and Ali  ----

I'm modifying the case like i need two reports like customer wise bill details,Bills In a date Range

So can i Code like

### BAL

```
class BALBill
{
     public dataset getCustWiseBillDetails()
     {
          DBManager oDBM=new DBManager()  //Class supporting db operations
          String strsql="select CustId,CustName,BillNo,BillAmt,Item,Amount FROM CustMst cm"
          strSql+="\n join BillingMst bm on bm.CustId=cm.CustId"
          strSql+="\n join BillingDet bd on bm.BillNo=bd.BillNo"
          retrun oDBM.fnExecute(strSQL);
     }

     public dataset getBillsInADateRange(DateTime dtFrom,DateTime dtTo)
     {
          DBManager oDBM=new DBManager()  //Class supporting db operations
          String strsql="select BillNo,BillAmt,Item,Amount FROM BillingMst bm on bm.CustId=cm.CustId"
          strSql+="\n join BillingDet bd on bm.BillNo=bd.BillNo"
          strSql+="\n where BillDate between " + dtFrom " and " + dtTo
          retrun oDBM.fnExecute(strSQL);
     }
     public sub SaveBillMst(BillingMst bM)
     {
           DBManager oDBM=new DBManager()  //Class supporting db operations
          String strsql="insert into BillingMst(BillNo,BillAmt)"
          strsql+="\n values(" + bM.BillNo + ", " +bM.BillAmt+")"
          oDBM.fnExecuteNonQuery(strSQL);
     }
     public sub SaveBillMst(List<BillingMst> bLM)
     {

          DBManager oDBM=new DBManager()  //Class supporting db operations
          foreach(BillingMst bM in BLM)
          {
             String strsql="insert into BillingMst(BillNo,BillAmt)"
             strsql+="\n values(" + bM.BillNo + ", " +bM.BillAmt+")"
             oDBM.fnExecuteNonQuery(strSQL);
          }
     }
     public sub SaveBillDet(BillingDet bD)
     {
           DBManager oDBM=new DBManager()  //Class supporting db operations
          String strsql="insert into BillingMst(BillId,Item,Amount)"
          strsql+="\n values(" + bD.BillNo + ", '" +bD.Item+"',"+bD.Amount+")"
          oDBM.fnExecuteNonQuery(strSQL);
     }
     public sub SaveBillDet(List<BillingDet> bLD)
     {

          DBManager oDBM=new DBManager()  //Class supporting db operations
          foreach(BillingMst bD in bLD)
          {
             String strsql="insert into BillingMst(BillNo,BillAmt)"
             strsql+="\n values(" + bM.BillNo + ", " +bM.BillAmt+")"
             oDBM.fnExecuteNonQuery(strSQL);
          }
     }
     public sub SaveBill(DALBill b)
     {
          saveBillMst(b.bM);
          saveBillDet(b.bLD);
     }
     public sub SaveBill(List<DALBill> bL)
     {
          foreach(DALBill b in bL)
          {
              saveBillMst(b.bM);
              saveBillDet(b.bLD);
           }             
     }
}
```

### DAL

```
class BillingMst
{
     public int BillId;
     public double BillAmt;
}
class BillingDet
{
     public int BillId;
     public string Item;
     public double Amount;
}
class DALBill
{
     public BillingMst bM;
     public List<BillingDet> bLD;
}
```

Am I on the right path?

Comment: This is completely unrelated, but when you use the abbreviation "e.g.", this means "for example" (you should never say "for e.g.").

Comment: What you mean by completely unrelated? 'My post is on wrong place' or 'I'm telling unrelated things? I have an inventory software which does not follow any standards. I'm trying to fit into an architecture because fed up by typing same code again and again. But to display things I have to use grids. At that time lots of joins will be there like some item may billed from challan. Some items will get return from billed etc. All these places i need to use "sql joins" to find what is in database? My question is where these operations will fit in my code?

Comment: I'm saying my comment is completely unrelated--it's not pertaining to your question, it's pertaining to your wording.  For future reference, when you say "e.g.", you should substitute the words "for example" and when you say "i.e." you should substitute the words "that is"--if those substitutions don't make grammatical or semantical sense, then you're using them incorrectly (I'm guilty of this a lot with "i.e.").

Answer (score 0):

You obviously put it in the class you use to read data from the database. You now have `CUD` objects (Create, Update, Delete), but you still need the Read.

The choice is up to you, but bear in mind that the approach you're using is not optimal. What if you want to insert 100 objects in a single transaction? Will you call `save()` on each object? Is the user responsible for the transaction?

A more standard approach is that you have a `DAO` (Data Access Object) for each object type, that would contain all (CRUD) the operations needed for it.

There are solutions similar to yours (such as Ebean), but you might want to learn the "basic" ways first, then check out JPA/Hibernate and other persistence solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I didn't start yet. So i need the best approach. Can you guide me on the above thing? Can you provide a sample with the example of bill(What will be in Data access,business layers)?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive these two tables would have relation between them, Every details record would have the `Master's PK` as `foreign key` , make a method of `GetByPK` which retrives record for the primray key provided in `BillingMaster` . In this way you can get info form both tables as simple as

```
BillingDetatil detail = new BillingDetatil();

detail.BillingMaster. // here you can access all the fields
```

Same you can do with master table, if you want to access all the child detail for that master, put a List in Master

You will do it in your `BLL Business Logic Layer`